# Not getting metadata record field values on lwc page using apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, custom-metadata

//Apex class

```java
public with sharing class getMetafieldController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getMetaList(){
        Organisation__mdt APIDetails = Organisation__mdt.getInstance('Country_1');
        system.debug('country: '+APIDetails.Country__c);
        String country= APIDetails.Country__c;
        return country;
    }
}
```

lwc.html

```html
<template>
   
    CountryName: {}
        
</template>
```

lwc.js

```javascript
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
// import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import getMeta from '@salesforce/apex/getMetafieldController.getMetaList';
// const FIELDS = ['Organisation__mdt.Country__c',];

export default class OrgMetaLWC extends LightningElement {

    // hello='helloUSA';

    // @api recordId;
    @track country;
    @wire(getMeta,{country:'$country'}) records;
    j(event){
        this.country=event.target.value;
        this.country=country;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. How would you expect to get the value you're looking for with incomplete code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

it's really not clear what you are trying to do and why you are doing it this way.

as is, your wired method will fire upon loading.

country amounts to undefined, since you are not assigning any value to the property.

`this.country = event.target.value` - does nothing.

you should be invoking your method imperatively. You should review [Call Apex Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex)

not only is the code incomplete, but, just wrong as is. If you are new to LWC, [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics) would be the best place to get started